# How to scrape text from div with empty class value

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Hi how to scrape text from div without any class? At first I try to scrape all data from div with class 'jobs page' then without class value but it doesn't work.

[image]

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

a = {}


def antal_pl(name=''):
    try:
        page_response = requests.get('https://antal.pl/oferty-pracy?s=&sid=&did=Accountancy', timeout=40).text
        page_content = BeautifulSoup(page_response, 'lxml')
        data = page_content.find_all(class_ = 'jobs_page')
        data_in = data.find_all('div', class_ = None)
        print(data_in)

    except:
        ''
antal_pl( name='Accontancy')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below approach to get the text out of that webpage as you mentioned above. I've tried to organize your code a little to make it look cleaner.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

URL = "https://antal.pl/oferty-pracy?s=&sid=&did={}"

def antal_pl(name):
    res = requests.get(URL.format(name))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
    data = soup.find(class_='header').find_next_sibling().text.strip()
    print(data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    antal_pl("Accountancy")
```

Result:

```
Znaleziono 47 ofert pracy.
```

Comment: Works! Thanks a lot. It was exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

use XPATH

```
html = etree.HTML(wb_data)
html_data = html.xpath('/html/body/div/ul/li/a')
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HG5ox.png)